# Waiting for an element to be in the DOM using promises or generator functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to use a promise when checking if an element is currently in the DOM. My idea is to get away from `setTimeOut` but really using `window.requestAnimationFrame` is exactly the same as `setTimeOut` only a little more performant.

```
const doCheck = function(selector){
    if (document.querySelector(selector) === null) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            doCheck(selector);
        });
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};

export default function checkElement(selector) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        doCheck(selector);
        res(true);
    })
}
```

But of course this cannot work, the major problem is the fact you call another function when the selector is not there, how can I encapsulate this with a promise? Seems to be that you cannot do something like this.

Comment: Why are you trying to get this information from the DOM? The code that adds the element to the DOM should provide you with that promise.

Comment: In addition to @Bergi's comment why exactly do you need to load `raf` with such polling work such as creating 60 promises every second etc. You could use either [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which seems to be the right way to take an action when something you follow changes in DOM. (like when a node gets appended to a parent etc) or  [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) but i suppose mutation events have performance issues and also depreciated in the favor of Mutation Observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `doCheck` function is asynchronous but neither takes a callback nor returns a promise. The promise inside `checkElement` is getting immediately resolved.

@Amit's answer shows how to pass around a callback (and use it instead of `return`), here's how to do it properly with promises:

```
function rafAsync() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
    });
}

export default function checkElement(selector) {
    if (document.querySelector(selector) === null) {
        return rafAsync().then(() => checkElement(selector));
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```

Since you were talking about generator functions, I assume you want to use `async`/`await`. You can do that recursively:

```
export default async function checkElement(selector) {
    if (document.querySelector(selector) === null) {
        await rafAsync();
        return checkElement(selector);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Or iteratively:

```
export default async function checkElement(selector) {
    while (document.querySelector(selector) === null) {
        await rafAsync()
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Brain fart time from me... I ran down a rabbit hole and just couldn't for the life of me work anything out lol so thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

you can send your resolve function and call it when you finish

```js
const doCheck = function(selector,resolve){
    if (document.querySelector(selector) === null) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            doCheck(selector,resolve);
        });
    } else {
        resolve(true);
    }
};


export default function checkElement(selector) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        doCheck(selector,res);
       
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     doCheck(selector);
>     res(true);
> ```

So on line one of the above you *start* polling for the element.

Then you immediately resolve the promise.

That won't work.

You need to resolve the promise **only when you've found the element**!

i.e. on this line:

> ```
>    return true;
> ```